# should be easy: how to access <header> element's inner text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a the following in html:

```
<header> ||| </header>
```

All I want is to change the "|||" using js but I can't figure out how to access it. Have tried .html, .val, .value, .innerHTML... just about everything with jquery but can't figure it out. Must be easy. Any ideas?

Comment: `.text()` or `.html()` -> http://jsfiddle.net/blgt/bJcRt/

Comment: You appear to be trying to use a few jquery methods in your attempts, can you show an actual usecase where you tried to solve this? and are you actually using jquery?

Comment: i'm an idiot. it was cause i had >1 elements returning and was pulling the first one like $('header')[0].... needed to do $('header:first')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below.

```
$('header').html('Hello world');

(or)

$('header').text('Hello world');
```

Above both statements working.

`innerHTML` works on DOM element

```
 $('header')[0].innerHTML = 'Hello world';
```

Answer (score 0):

$('header').html();

should work.

I just tested it.

Make sure the script is called AFTER the header tag is used.

Comment: And why the downvote if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to run this when after the DOM loaded?

```
$(function() {
  // This code will run after the DOM has loaded
  // Otherwise jQuery might not know about the <header> element
  alert($("header").text());
});
```